# Silverstripe 3.4 load content via ajax / Shortcode issue

Tags: ajax, silverstripe

Shortcodes dont render correctly.

I am loading content via ajax into bootstrap-tabs.

calling ajax works.

routes are ok.

I've tried `renderWith()`, `customise()` ....

No matter what i try, the shortcodes don't render. Please help.

```
class EventPage_Controller extends Page_Controller {

public function EventDetail(SS_HTTPRequest $request){

        if($request){

            $group = DataObject::get_one('Group', "\"Code\" = 'eventgroup'");
            $member = Member::currentUser();
            if($member && $member->inGroup($group->ID)){

                if($event = DataObject::get_by_id('Event', intval($request->param('eventID')))){

                    $eventDetail = array(
                        'EventTitle' => $event->Name,
                        'EventContent' => $event->Content
                    );

                    /* if( Director::is_ajax() ) {

                        return $this->renderWith('EventDetail', json_encode(array('EventContent' => $event->Content)));
                    }*/
                    //return $this->customise($eventDetail)->renderWith(array('EventDetail', 'Page'));
                    //echo $event->Content;

                    echo  json_encode(array('error' =>  '0', 'EventContent' => $event->Content));

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

javascript:

```
$('#event-detail').hide();
        $('.event-detail-btn').on('click', function(e){
            //alert('click');
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
            if($(this).parent().is('tr')){
                //alert('TR');
                var eventID = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[1];
                var dateID = $(this).parent().attr('id').split('_')[2];
                //alert(eventID + '_' + dateID);
                getEventDetail(eventID, dateID);
            }
            $('#event-detail, #member-enrolment').toggle();
        });


        function getEventDetail(eventID, dateID){

            //$('#eventDetail').load('Enrolment/EventDetail/'+ eventID + '/' +dateID);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'Enrolment/EventDetail/'+ eventID + '/' +dateID,
                dataType: "json"
                }).success(function(msg){
                    $('#eventDetail').html(msg.EventContent);
            });
        }
```

Page.ss

```
<div id="enrolments" class="tab-pane fade">


        <% include EventDetail %>
        <% include MemberEnrolments %>


</div> <!--end enrolments-->
```

EventDetail.ss

```
<div id="event-detail">
    <br><br>
    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="event-detail-btn btn btn-default btn-sm">zurück</button></a>
    <br><br>

    <div id="eventDetail"></div>

    <a href="#"><button type="button" class="event-detail-btn btn btn-default btn-sm">zurück</button></a>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes are not automatically rendered when you're not calling them from a template, try:

```
$eventDetail = array(
    'EventTitle' => $event->Name,
    'EventContent' => $event->Content->forTemplate() //this is a HTMLText
);
```

or on SS3.4:

```
$eventDetail = array(
    'EventTitle' => $event->Name,
    'EventContent' => $event->Content->RAW() //this is a HTMLText
);
```

If this still doesn't work you might do it the hard way and call `ShortcodeParser` manually:

```
ShortcodeParser::get_active()->parse($event->Content);
```

Also, you might use `Director::is_ajax()` to check if it's really an ajax call and output the ajax response or - as a fallback - the whole page including ajax content. See [lessons](https://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/ajax-behaviour-and-viewabledata) or [docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3.4/developer_guides/templates/rendering_templates/)

Comment: Thank you very much! ShortcodeParser::get_active()->parse($event->Content) did the trick. This answered my question and accepted.